# remote server node debug,node --inspect is not hitting the break point in chrome inspect dev tool

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, ssh-tunnel

my nodejs (node version v10.5.0) server is runnig on `159.65.151.135:3000`

I have the ssh tunneling from my local windows machine to server as `ssh -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 user@159.65.151.135 -v`

but `node --inspect app.js` is not hitting the breakpoint in `chrome://inspect` Devtool

Please help in resolving the issue

steps that I did

1. execute the command `ssh -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 user@159.65.151.135
   -v` in CMD
2. open the server console and start node server with the command node --inspect app.js
3. open chrome and goto `chrome://inspect`, check the Remote Target link and click to open the Devtool
4. Put breakpoints in the desired locations by opening the source file by Ctr+P
5. in chrome load the  url of my nodejs app , ie `159.65.151.135:3000`

But for any action, breakpoint is not getting hit. I have tried with `node --inspect-brk app.js`, only the first line will get paused, after that no breakpoint execution.

Comment: i solved this issue by using debug-brk, then put break point, then let it run (it wont pause at break point), then shutdown debugger and node, restart it. then breakpoint previously put will works